# Gensim Predict Output Word Function Syntax

Tags: gensim

How do you use the Gensim predict output word function?

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)

model.predict_output_word(['Hi', 'how', 'you'], topn=10)

AttributeError: 'Word2VecKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'predict_output_word'
```

I tried Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True), which was deprecated as well.

Answer (score 3):

A file like `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin` only contains the word vectors, not the complete model used for training. So it is not possible to use `predict_output_word` in this case. If you would have trained a full model yourself and saved it with `model.save()`, then the method `predict_output_word` would be available.